# Issue with windowTranslucentStatus with AppCompat v22

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, transparent, android-studio-2.0

I have an issue with making my **Status Bar** **transparent** respectively translucent. I am using **AppCompat v22** Theme. I want to use **windowTranslucentStatus** for API >=19. I really searched for answers on stackoverflow, but i could not find any solution for my problem.
I think the easiest way is to show you my code and screenshots from my smartphone I tested the app with.

```
<RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/activitylayout"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Above the code for my Activity layout.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/drawerarrowstyle1</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

My style.xml(v19) code.
**The problem: My Status Bar has a white background and in the nav drawer it is not even visible.**

[Screenshot of the Status Bar in Activity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED9ax.png)

[Screenshot of Status Bar in Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MrF3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things are help me in the same problem.

1. Correct layout file. Scrollable View above Appbar.

   ```
        <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                     ...
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                     ...
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
2. `android:fitsSystemWindows="true|false"`
3. Style define:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.TransparentStatusBar">
       <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

exact your problem probably in point 2.